# Python/PIL Resize all images in all subfolder and save as new file name

Tags: python, resize, subdirectory

I am going to resize image file which located in Desktop with set of subfolder.

I try following command and it works without rename save new.

```py
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import glob
root_dir='./././Desktop/python/'

def resize():
    for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/*.jpg', recursive=True):
        print(filename)
        im = Image.open(filename)
        imResize = im.resize((450,600), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        imResize.save(filename , 'JPEG', quality=90)
        
resize()
```

My question is how can I add the correct command to save the renewe resized image file with append `'f + _thumbnail' + .jpg`?
E.g `file1 > file1_thumbnail.jpg`

I tried add followings to row `print(filename)` but show error.

```py
             f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
             size = im.size
             ratio = float(final_size) / max(size)
             new_image_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in size])
             im = im.resize(new_image_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
             new_im = Image.new("RGB", (final_size, final_size))
             new_im.paste(im, ((final_size-new_image_size[0])//2, (final_size-new_image_size[1])//2))
             new_im.save(f + 'resized.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=90)
```

May I know how can fix it?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use python slicing of strings for this -
You can modify your code to -

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys
import glob
root_dir='./././Desktop/python/'

def resize():
    for filename in glob.iglob(root_dir + '**/*.jpg', recursive=True):
        print(filename)
        im = Image.open(filename)
        imResize = im.resize((450,600), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        filename = filename[:-4] + " _thumbnail" + filename[-4:]
        imResize.save(filename , 'JPEG', quality=90)
    
resize()
```

The ".jpg" can be sliced at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.

May I know how to resize with aspect ratio?

Comment: To properly maintain aspect ratio you need to either keep a fixed height and calculate new width or else keep image width fixed and calculate the new height. If you keep both width and height fixed, then you need to rely on PIL's resizing method. If you don't want to calculate then, you may try PIL's contain method. It can maintain aspect ratio. More info at this link - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/8.3.0.html?highlight=aspect%20ratio#imageops-contain

Comment: Hi YadenshD

Thanks for your help but still have problem as followings:

Comment: please give more details @ftktsoi01